# Python join not giving back comma separated string

Tags: python, django

I have a Django query that returns me an array of strings.
I am trying to convert them into a comma separated string.

```
array_string = "['xyz2005.test.com', 'xyz2006.test.com']"


(Pdb) joined_string = ",".join(array_string)
(Pdb) joined_string
"[,',x,y,z,2,0,0,5,.,t,e,s,t,.,c,o,m,',,, ,',x,y,z,2,0,0,6,.,t,e,s,t,.,c,o,m,',]"
```

I was expecting:

```
xyz2005.test.com, xyz2006.test.com
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed. Decode the array using array_string = json.loads(array_string) first. Then use join.

Comment: @OneLiner: I am getting this error on  array_string = json.loads(array_string):
*** simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: Would need to see your exact code, including the import. Are you importing loads from json?